# View and controller both not being loaded to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I had my angular app loading my javascript properly before but it was not set up properly for routing. I am trying to fix that but now my javascript alert will not even pop up which means the file is not connected. Can someone tell me why the partial searchRadius.html is not being loaded into index.html? Am I properly rendering the view near the bottom of index.html with: `<div ui-view></div>`?

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="example/assets/stylesheets/example.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="website_libs/dev_deps.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="dist/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.underscore.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/0.0.1/dist/index.js"></script><script src="dist/angular-google-maps_dev_mapped.js"></script>
      <script src="getLoc.js"></script>
      <script src="searchRadius.js"></script>
      <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_g7xCYEi-U54SYfTXQ_lukRsChkWgjXQ'></script>
      <title>Pet Locate</title>
      <!--NEW STUFF FROM TOM-->
   </head>
   <body style="height: 100%">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">Pet Locate</h1>
      <div ui-view></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**searchRadius.js:**

```
(function(window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.router'])

    .config(function($stateProvider) { //had: , $stateChangeError included in the function parameters, but that caused error 
        $stateProvider.state('location', {
            url: '/:lat/:lon',
            templateUrl: 'searchRadius.html', //changed from  index to searchRadius.html
            controller: 'MapsCtrl',

            resolve: {
                resolveMap: function(MapService, $stateParams) {
                    return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon).then(function(rsp) {
                        console.log(rsp);
                        return rsp;
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                }
            }
        });

    })

    .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function(GoogleMapApi) {
        GoogleMapApi.configure({
            key: 'AIzaSyCbRPhVlxgVwBC0bBOgyB-Dn_K8ONrxb_g',
            v: '3',
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
        });
    }])


    .controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams", 'resolveMap',
        function($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams) {
            $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
            var center = {
                latitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lat),
                longitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lon)
            };
            alert(JSON.stringify(center));
            //Object.freeze(center); caused TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ('latitude') ...

            console.log($stateParams);

            $scope.map = {
                center: center,
                pan: false,
                zoom: 16,
                refresh: false,
                events: {},
                bounds: {}
            };

            $scope.map.circle = {
                id: 1,
                center: center,
                radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
                stroke: {
                    color: '#08B21F',
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1
                },

                fill: {
                    color: '#08B21F',
                    opacity: 0.5
                },
                geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
                draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
                clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
                editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
                visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
                events: {
                    dblclick: function() {
                        $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                    },
                    radius_changed: function(gObject) {
                        var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                        $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                    }
                }
            }




            //Increase Radius:
            $interval(function() {
                $scope.map.circle.radius += 30; //dynamic var
                $state.transitionTo('location', { //location is the state name
                    center: $stateParams.center,
                    radius: $scope.map.circle.radius
                }, {
                    notify: false
                });
            }, 1000); //end of interval function


        }
    ]); //end of controller

})(window, angular);
```

**searchRadius.html:**

```
<div style="height: 100%">
   <!--took out: ng-if="map.center !== undefined"-->
   <ui-gmap-google-map 
      center='map.center'
      zoom='map.zoom'
      draggable='map.draggable'
      dragging='map.dragging'
      refresh='map.refresh'
      options='map.options'
      events='map.events'
      pan='map.pan'>
      <ui-gmap-circle 
         center='map.circle.center'
         radius='map.circle.radius'
         fill='map.circle.fill'
         stroke='map.circle.stroke'
         clickable='map.circle.clickable'
         draggable='map.circle.draggable'
         editable='map.circle.editable'
         visible='map.circle.visible'
         events='map.circle.events'>
      </ui-gmap-circle>
   </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some issue with below code in your route config.

```
resolve: {
    resolveMap: function (MapService, $stateParams) {
        return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon).then(function (rsp){console.log(rsp); return rsp; }).catch(function (err){console.log(err);}) 
     }
}
```

can you remove this and load the page again ?
Also are you getting any errors in developer tools console while loading ?

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much! The alert now properly shows the correct lat and lon (which are pulled in from the url). But the page is still blank! No errors are showing in the console

Comment: In your searchRadius.html add a simple tag like <h1>SearchRadius</h1>, and check whether its showing or not. Then we can see whether template html is loading.

Comment: The page is actually loading properly now, you rock